# Preventing bounty reward assignment

Tags: discussion

How can I avoid assigning a reward for the bounty I opened, when all the answers to the question are too bad and don't really answer it?
AFAIK even if I don't assign it manually, it will be assigned automatically to some arbitrary answer.